# Rails running association's validations when creating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have three classes

```
class a
  has_many :b
  has_many :c, through: b
end

class b
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :c
end

class c
  has_many :b
  has_many :a, through: :b
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

If somehow 2 objects of class `c` are in the database with the same `name` value when I try to create an instance of class `a` I was surprised to see that the validations on class `c` are run! 
Why are the validations run when I should not be touching the class `c` row at all?

@max asked for an example.

After creating a new Rails 5 project do:

```
rails g model a 
rails g model c name:string
rails g model b a:references c:references
```

Edit a.rb to look like:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :b
  has_many :c, through: :b
end
```

Edit c.rb to look like:

```
class C < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :b
  has_many :a, through: :b
end
```

In rails console do:

```
C.create(name: 'first')
C.create(name: 'first')
```

Modify class C to add:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
```

In rails console:

```
 A.create!(c_ids: [1])
```

And you'll get an exception:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: C is invalid)
```

As I said, I know the data is wrong but I am just surprised that the validation is being run. I do not think this was happening in Rails 4.

Comment: How can `class B` belong to `class B` ?

Comment: Was the model validation on C added after there was already more than one of that particular name?

Comment: Are you accepting nested attributes, or are you writing an array called  `c_ids` for records in class a?

Comment: Can you please create a minimal verifiable example that that demonstrates the behavior you are talking about?

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery yes

Comment: @max added how to create an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many` associations validate associations by default. If you wanted to get around this, you could set the `validate` key on the `has_many` associations to be `false` (it is true by default). You can see more options for `has_many` here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Comment: Fascinating! I am of two minds as to whether this is the right thing to do, but thanks for explaining it.

Comment: I agree that overriding that key probably isn't the right thing to do!